# Level + Scale model estimation

Tags: regression

Consider a model of level and exponential scale given by
$$z = \underbrace{e^{\gamma'Y}}_{\text{scale}}\underbrace{\beta'X}_{\text{level}} + \epsilon,$$
where

- $z$ is the vector of observations of dependent variables,
- $X$ is the matrix of observations of independent level variables,
- $Y$ is the matrix of observations of independent scale variables (with no constant columns),
- $\beta$ is the vector of level coefficients, and
- $\gamma$ is the vector of scale coefficients.

Are there any consensus ways to estimate it?

Comment: Could you please explain what your symbols mean?  In particular, is there any meaning intended by not capitalizing $z$ but capitalizing $Y$ and $X$?  What do you mean by "scale" if not $e^{\gamma^\prime Y}$ and how could that possibly be negative?

Comment: My original post was a bit cryptic. I added more details.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this model is not identifiable: it has too many parameters.  This is obvious when $X$ and $Y$ have just one column apiece, but the problem is general.  I doubt there is any "consensus," because appropriate estimation procedures will depend on your loss function: this expresses how you are willing to trade off accuracy in estimating $\gamma$ for accuracy in estimating $\beta,$ and is also related to the distributional assumptions you make about $\epsilon.$

Comment: Would the identifiability situation be fixed if $Y$ is binary?

Comment: The problem is that when a constant vector is in the column space of $Y,$ all the betas can be rescaled and the coefficient of the constant vector can be adjusted to compensate perfectly for that: there is the redundancy.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I'll rule that out as a hypothesis.